# Não mover com Mouse o <p:dialog>

Tags: java-ee, jsf, xhtml

Pergunta besta porem não achei em canto nenhum, gostaria de não permitir o usuário mover o p:dialog aberto.

```
<p:dialog header="#{MyBean.select.projetos.nome}" widgetVar="lanDialog" modal="false" showEffect="blind" resizable="false">
 ...meu código...
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar o atributo `draggable` como `false`.

Por exemplo:

```
<p:dialog header="#{MyBean.select.projetos.nome}" widgetVar="lanDialog" modal="false" 
          showEffect="blind" resizable="false" draggable="false">
    <!-- códigos -->
</p:dialog>
```

Na página 181 da [documentação](https://speakerdeck.com/player/057b8d7962d2466f9f24cd45f559b8da?slide=181#) tem mais especificações do componente.
Você também pode baixar a documentação completa do PrimeFaces [aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation).

Comment: Isso ae @Luidne

Comment: Muito obrigado! não tinha achado na internet nenhum exemplo.